# oracle update stored procedure with user defined exception

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, exception

I am trying to create this stored procedure which should take customer no and email address as input. Then update the email address for that customer. if new email address is same as old then exception should be raised.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UpdateEmail
(CUSTOMERID IN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERNO%TYPE, 
 N_EMAIL IN CUSTOMER.EMAIL%TYPE)

IS
DECLARE 
  e_same EXCEPTION;
  V_ROWCOUNT NUMBER;

BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(EMAIL)
INTO V_ROWCOUNT
FROM CUSTOMER@FIT5148B
WHERE CUSTOMER.EMAIL = N_EMAIL
AND CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERNO = CUSTOMERID;

IF V_ROWCOUNT > 0

THEN RAISE e_same;
ELSE 
UPDATE CUSTOMER
SET EMAIL = N_EMAIL
WHERE CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERNO = CUSTOMERID;
END IF;

EXCEPTION
 WHEN e_same THEN dbms_output.put_line ('email address exist');
END;
/
```

But it is throwing error. Not sure if I am doing it right. I am using the latest Oracle SQL Developer.

> Error(6,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting
>   one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type
>        current
>   cursor delete    exists prior external language The symbol "begin" was
>   substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.
>   Error(28,4): PLS-00103:
>   Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the
>   following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if
>   loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open
>   rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

Comment: Remove `Declare`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `DECLARE` .

You should not use `Declare` in a Procedure. If you are writing a PLSQL block then only you should use `Declare`. Not in an actual Procedure body.

Comment: Thanks @Utsav for the explanation.